# Wireless and Wired Network - iPad and Windows Proxy

Tags: networking, proxy, android, ipad

I'm a developer trying to simplify the process of multi-platform web development and I would like to setup a proxy in windows 10 for an iPad or other device to use.

Specifically I have an [Android Phone](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00EZW9UXW) and an [iPad Air](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00G2TK76A) which I want to be able to logically see and communicate with my workstation which hosts a HTTP server, but using a specific host name (functional requirement of the website, hosts multiple websites using custom route controller that does a lookup on the sub-domain in a database, unrecognized traffic gets a 404.)

How can I coerce their traffic such that 'bla.bla.bla.com' or '*.bla.com' goes to the workstation?

In windows it's an easy modification of the [hosts](http://winhelp2002.mvps.org/hosts.htm) file, I lack the networking experience to know what software works with Windows 10, but I know it **should** be possible.  I'm using a Ubee cable modem/wireless router combo in the event that there's some router-level settings I can use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up faking it:

Instead of going through the trouble of finding a proxy that would work with the setup, I modified the code to enable target redirects, so if it finds: 'x' it'll replace it with 'y' before doing the routing.

The net effect is: 192.168.x.x becomes sub.domain.com.